# Quaternion.LookRotation Angle Not Working Correctly

Tags: unity-game-engine, angle, quaternions

I have been trying something for a while, and cannot figure out why it is not working. 
I have a simple path of empty objects in a PathHolder parent and a character object which follows that path and rotates smoothly to face the point it is going towards. My problem is that half of the time, the character object does not rotate all the way and yet still moves towards the point as it should. 
The other weird thing is that moving the point closer will decrease how much the object will rotate, and moving it further will actually make the character face the point. However, the path needs to be flexible as to work in any situation, so I cannot let distance affect the rotation.

Ideally, i'd want the character to fully and smoothly rotate towards the point when the arrow key is pressed, so that the character isn't stuck mid turn if the player releases the key. Here is the code I have so far:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CharacterControllerPath : MonoBehaviour 
{
    enum Direction {Forward, Backward};
    Direction charDirection;

    public PathEditor pathToFollow;

    private Vector3 targetPosition;

    public string pathName;
    public int wayPointID = 0;
    public float speed;
    public float rotationSpeed = 7.0f;

    private float reachDistance = 1.0f;
    private float distanceX;
    private float distanceY;

    void Start () 
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(pathToFollow.pathObj[wayPointID].transform.position.x, transform.position.y, pathToFollow.pathObj[wayPointID].transform.position.z);
        charDirection = Direction.Forward;
        Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3(pathToFollow.pathObj[wayPointID + 1].transform.position.x, transform.position.y, pathToFollow.pathObj[wayPointID + 1].transform.position.z);
        transform.LookAt(targetPosition);
    }

    void FixedUpdate () 
    {
        Movement();
    }

    void Movement()
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            charDirection = Direction.Forward;

            //Move
            targetPosition = new Vector3(pathToFollow.pathObj[wayPointID].transform.position.x, transform.position.y, pathToFollow.pathObj[wayPointID].transform.position.z);
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);

            //Rotate
            targetPosition = new Vector3(pathToFollow.pathObj[wayPointID].transform.position.x, 0, pathToFollow.pathObj[wayPointID].transform.position.z);
            var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPosition);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);

            if(transform.position.x == targetPosition.x && transform.position.z == targetPosition.z)
                wayPointID++;
        }
        else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            charDirection = Direction.Backward;

            //Move
            targetPosition = new Vector3(pathToFollow.pathObj[wayPointID - 1].transform.position.x, transform.position.y, pathToFollow.pathObj[wayPointID - 1].transform.position.z);
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);

            //Rotate
            targetPosition = new Vector3(pathToFollow.pathObj[wayPointID - 1].transform.position.x, 0, pathToFollow.pathObj[wayPointID - 1].transform.position.z);
            var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPosition);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);

            if(transform.position.x == targetPosition.x && transform.position.z == targetPosition.z)
                wayPointID--;
        }

        if(wayPointID >= pathToFollow.pathObj.Count)
        {
            //Put code to finish the level
            wayPointID = (pathToFollow.pathObj.Count - 1);
        }
        else if(wayPointID <= 0)
            wayPointID = 0;
    }   
}
```

Comment: I assume that the points in `pathToFollow` to world-relative? If you want a character to look in that direction, you'll need to make sure you're giving a vector that's relative to that character.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! However, I'm not sure I fully understand what you are saying, do you have an example in mind?

Comment: never use quaternions for any reason in Unity. simply use "LookAt"  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html

Comment: The problem with Vector3.LookAt is that it snaps the character to abruptly. My character is following a path and needs to rotate smoothly as to make the game more fluid.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move a Vector smoothly between two vectors, use

```
Vector3.Lerp(firstPosOrRotation, secondPosOrRotation, Time.deltaTime*Input.GetInputRaw("Horizontal")*speed);
```

Input.GetInputRaw("Horizontal") is just a value between -1 and 1 depending on the arrow keys being pressed.
Now just get each point and the next point in the path and Lerp between them.

- Edit
  For rotation, instead of the Time.deltaTime and all that, do this

  rotation = Vector3.Lerp(rotationA, rotationB, Mathf.Clamp(dist(pos,
    finalPos), 0, 1);

  dist(pos,
    finalPos) = amount travelled between point A and B

I hope this is clear enough,
I am not sure if you mean that or you want the object to face forward on the path.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as mentionned, the movement works just fine and I can move from one point to the other, the problem is that the character is not facing the right way at times even with my quaternion.LookRotation(). I have a path that goes straight, then right, then left, and the character is following it simply by pressing the right arrow, however, when moving towards the first point, the character does not rotate all the way and is at a 232.52 degree angle, then past that point, when it turns towards the next point, it's facing it perfectly.

Comment: Okay, for the position do what I said, but for the rotation do the Vector3.Lerp  but replace Time.deltaTime and all that other stuff with how far the object has moved between the two path points and clamp that between 0 and 1